# Can we optimize huge Woff2 File?

Tags: css, image-optimization

I have 3 huge woff2 font files(due to bussiness requirement). One file is 2MB in size. I have read somewhere that woff2 is by default compress so gzip is not helping me. So any way to optimize it or make it lighter?

Comment: Exclude glyphs you don't need.

Comment: @Stijn I am using NotoSansTC-Light.woff2. Can you please explain how?

Comment: Take a look at the common online web font generators (the ones that let you upload TTF files etc), some of them allow you to select the glyphs you need. You'll get a modified font file containing only the glyphs you need then, which will reduce the size.